# Mixing numbered and unnumbered lines in VB6

Tags: vb6, basic

I remember being a kid in the 1980s and numbering lines in BASIC because you had to.  Nowadays, as far as I knew, numbered lines were 100% out; no one wants or needs to use them.  That's until I discovered some legacy code I needed to work on.  Every function has its lines numbered in increments of 10.  My question is, are there any negative ramifications to using a mix of numbered and unnumbered lines?  For example, if I'm modifying a function, can I just remove all the numbering from that function only without having any problems?  I really don't feel like trying to maintain such an arcane system if I don't need to, but I also don't think there's any major benefit to clearing out all the numbering for the entire project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, line numbers in VB6 are only helpful for error handling.  Something like this:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

    Dim i As Long

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

10:     i = 20
20:     i = i / 2
30:     i = i / 0

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:

    MsgBox ("Error on line: " & Erl)

End Sub
```

When you run this code, it will say "Error on line 30".  There is a free tool for VB6 called [MZ Tools](http://www.mztools.com/v3/mztools3.aspx) that is a plug in for VB6.  This tool can add/remove line numbers as well as insert error handling for you.  I encourage you to take a look at it.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  Yes, I hadn't noticed the code was using the Erl variable, or what it was.  This ended up being a moot point because the solution to the problem was to rip out the entire offending function.  I appreciate the information though.

Comment: Thanks for doing that, @MarkJ .